Why does python successfully open a file when the filename is incorrect?
I accidentally asked a python program to open a file with the wrong name -- with an extra . on the end, and it worked.
So I started experimenting:
>>> open('myfile.txt')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='fruit.iml' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
>>> open('myfile.txt.')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='fruit.iml.' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
>>> open('myfile.txt. ')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='fruit.iml. ' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
>>> open('myfile.txt. x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myfile.txt. x'

Why is it accepting filenames with extra whitespace or periods at the end? How generous is Python's open?

TL;DR: from the equivalent question linked: this is not a Python thing - it is a Windows API thing, which Python happens to call transparently.  "."s in filenames in Posix (Linux, Mac, etc) are deterministic.

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/230385/dots-at-the-end-of-file-name which also mentions such dots and trailing spaces in the windows api
